# Command line: Show list of options and let user choose

Tags: python

Assuming I have a list of options:

```
options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
```

And I would like the user to choose an option on the command line, e.g. something like this:

```
Please choose:
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
Enter number: <user input>
```

So I am looking for the implementation of the following:

```
choice = let_user_pick(options) # returns integer
```

How would one go about this in python?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def let_user_pick(options):
    print("Please choose:")
    for idx, element in enumerate(options):
        print("{}) {}".format(idx+1,element))
    i = input("Enter number: ")
    try:
        if 0 < int(i) <= len(options):
            return int(i)
    except:
        pass
    return None
```

You might want to instead return `int(i)-1` in order to use the result as an index of your options list, or return the option directly. It might also be good to instead of returning None loop over the whole thing until the user enters a correct choice.